# How do you return an object with a fat arrow function without rebinding this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

I have a simple function (within a React component):

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    text: this.props.text
  }
}
```

But I want to fat arrowify it:

```
getInitialState: () => {
    text: this.props.text
}
```

except I get an error, because a `{` after a fat arrow means a block of code that returns undefined (unless you explicitly `return` something). At least that's what I thought at first. But I think `this` is being bound now to that fat arrow function and now `this.props` is `undefined`.

So I try this:

```
getInitialState: () => new Object({
    text: this.props.text
})
```

But I get the same error, `this.props` is undefined.

So I guess I have 2 issues I'm curious about. First, what's the idiomatic way to return an object from a simple statement fat arrow function? Second, how do I return an object that has a reference to the `this` object of the surrounding context?

Comment: Arrow  functions retain context, but when you use `new` it will reset `this` and hence you will get error. If you want this to work, you can go back to ES5 hack `var self = this`

Comment: It's called an "arrow function", not a "fat arrow function"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surround it with parenthesis, like this

```
getInitialState: () => ({
    text: this.props.text
})
```

without the parenthesis, the object literal looks also like a JavaScript block with a label called `text` in it. Since it is ambiguous, the SyntaxError is thrown. But when you surround it with `()`, JavaScript knows that it is an Object literal.

---

> I think this is being bound now to that arrow function

Arrow functions don't have `this`. When `this` is encountered in an arrow function, it will go to previous level to see if `this` is available there and use that. You can confirm that, like this

```
(function Test1() {
  console.log(this);
  (() => console.log(this))();
}).bind({a: 1})();
```

would print

```
{ a: 1 }
{ a: 1 }
```

In your case, `this` will refer the `this` object of the function in which it is declared, not the object itself.